# Doctrine 2 removes parent row

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I have defined two database entities

Project:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use \Kdyby\Doctrine\Entities\MagicAccessors;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Project extends \Kdyby\Doctrine\Entities\BaseEntity
{


    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    public $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     * @var string
     */
    public $description;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     * @var DateTime
     */
    public $created;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     * @var string
     */
    public $public;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="blob")
     * @var string
     */
    public $thumbnail;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->created = new \DateTime();
        $this->public = 0;
    }

}
```

and Personage:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use \Kdyby\Doctrine\Entities\MagicAccessors;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Personage extends \Kdyby\Doctrine\Entities\BaseEntity
{


    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    public $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     * @var string
     */
    public $shortDescription;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     * @var string
     */
    public $playerDescription;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @var DateTime
     */
    public $created;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @var string
     */
    public $creator;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", options={"default" = false})
     * @var boolean
     */
    public $inGraph;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=false, options={"default" = 0})
     * @var boolean
     */
    public $deleted;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Project", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="project", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     * @var string
     */
    public $project_id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->deleted = 0;
        $this->inGraph = 0;
    }
}
```

Every Personage entity belongs to some project. But whenever I try to remove Personage either this way:

```
public function removeChar($id)
    {
        $a = $this->EntityManager->find('App\Personage', $id);

        if($a->deleted)
        {
            $this->EntityManager->remove($a);
            $this->EntityManager->flush();
        }

    }
```

or using dql. It removes the whole project row as well. What i want is whenever project is removed it removes all characters corresponding but NOT other way around.

I tried to remove

```
cascade={"persist", "remove"}
```

part from Project entity declaration (and updating database via console) but it said everything was in sync and did nothing. So I removed whole database and build it without `cascade={"persist", "remove"}`, but the problem was not solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove onDelete="CASCADE" from

`@ORM\JoinColumn(name="project", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")`

and add

```
@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Personage", mappedBy="project_id",cascade={"remove"})
private $personages;
```

in the project entity.

Comment: What does this do? Should mappedBy be with dolar sign?

Comment: when a project is deleted should be deleted too the personages related